# Pandas .count() puts in first row name out of nowhere?

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, where the first row is called school and the last row is called passed, and it has only numbers 1 and 0.

I simply wanted to count how often 1 or 0 occurs in that row.

i went with :

```
n_passed = df[df.passed==1].count()
```

the funny thing is, it gives me the correct number, but also outputs 'school', for a reason that is beyond me.

school        265

Can anyone bring light into this ?

Comment: Post raw input data, code to reproduce your df, code you tried, and desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you think no rows, but columns `passed` and `school`. Then you can use [value_counts](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with column `passed`:

```
print df
   school  aa  bb  passed
0       1   0   1       1
1       0   1   0       0
2       1   1   0       1
3       0   0   1       1

n_passed1 = df.passed[df.passed==1].value_counts()
print n_passed1
1    3
Name: passed, dtype: int64

n_passed0 = df.passed[df.passed==0].value_counts()
print n_passed0
0    1
Name: passed, dtype: int64
```

But I think the best is use:

```
n_passed1 = df.passed.value_counts()
print n_passed1
1    3
0    1
Name: passed, dtype: int64
```